# WPF How to change the listbox selected item text color when the list box loses focus

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles, selecteditem

I've been searching for how to change the text color of a selected item in a list box that has lost focus.

```
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Orange"/>
```

These three tags take care of most of the work, but my list box has a black background and when the control loses focus, the font turns to black.

I found this list from another post [SystemColor. Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors_members.aspx) that gives a ton of possible options from this list and anything that seems remotely intuitive has not worked.  Does anybody know the key that I need to change?

Answer (score 9):

I put this in a resource dictionary for an element containing the listbox:

```
               <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <!--SelectedItem with focus-->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
                    <!--SelectedItem without focus-->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Blue"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
```

Notice also that in .Net 4.5 you have to ask for "old" behavior by setting

```
      FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.
            AreInactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKeysSupported = false;
```

early in your program before any windows are created.

Answer (score 1):

use following code and just change the colors for example by using `Colors.Black`

```
listBox.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x7F, 0xDB, 0x14)));
listBox.Resources.Add(SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey, Brushes.White);
```

Good luck.