# Setting Background Color or WPF (4.0) ListBox - Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

I am attempting to set the background color of a selected ListBoxItem to be white rather than the system color.  I have read what I could find here on SO and have followed, or believed to have followed the recommendations there ([Change background color for selected ListBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item/2138237#2138237), [WPF How to change the listbox selected item text color when the list box loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111763/wpf-how-to-change-the-listbox-selected-item-text-color-when-the-list-box-loses-f), [Change selected and unfocused Listbox style to not be grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698830/change-selected-and-unfocused-listbox-style-to-not-be-grayed-out), and others).

All seem to solve the problem by setting the HighlightBrush and ControlBrush to Transparent for the selected item.  I have the following XAML and it sets the font color properly, but the backgroound is the default transparent blue regardless of the brush settings.  I am still a bit of a WPF noob, so I must be missing something simple here.

```
<ListBox Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFF3F3F3" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
       <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
          <sys:String>String 1</sys:String>
          <sys:String>String 2</sys:String>
          <sys:String>String 3</sys:String>
          <sys:String>String 4</sys:String>
       </x:Array>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
          <Style.Resources>
             <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
             <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
          </Style.Resources>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#999999"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
             </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,8,0" Background="Transparent"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

I would appreciate any nudges in the right direction.

**EDIT**:

After reading the first answer that it worked for them with a slight change, I took the application that I have been developing on my Windows 8 machine and executed it in a Windows 7 VM and it worked as expected.  Any ideas on what needs to change to get this to work on a Windows 8 machine as well as a Windows 7?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Those posts are getting outdated for Windows-8.

In Windows-8 for some reason Microsoft don't want people editing their Default `Style`'s so easily or something with a `Brush` over-ride.

`ListBoxItem` default `Style` from VS has this for selection triggers:

```
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                Value="False" />
    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True" />
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="Background"
          Value="#3DDADADA" />
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="#FFDADADA" />
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                Value="True" />
    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True" />
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="Background"
          Value="#3D26A0DA" />
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="#FF26A0DA" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

Triggers for Selection state no longer are applying brushes we can over-ride easily but are static colors. Hence to modify it you are going to need to derive the template and modify the trigger there. to `White`

This is the full Style given by VS2012 Windows-8 for `ListBoxItem`

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="4,1" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                         AncestorLevel=1,
                                                         AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                         AncestorLevel=1,
                                                         AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Style>
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
              <Rectangle Margin="2"
                         SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                         Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                         StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                         StrokeThickness="1" />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Border x:Name="Bd"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="#1F26A0DA" />
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#A826A0DA" />
          </MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                         Value="False" />
              <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                         Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="#3DDADADA" />
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#FFDADADA" />
          </MultiTrigger>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                         Value="True" />
              <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                         Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="#3D26A0DA" />
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#FF26A0DA" />
          </MultiTrigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                   Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                    Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

if you modify those triggers to:

```
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                Value="False" />
    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True" />
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="Background"
          Value="White" />
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="White" />
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                Value="True" />
    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                Value="True" />
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="Background"
          Value="White" />
  <Setter TargetName="Bd"
          Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="White" />
</MultiTrigger>
```

you should have your issue sorted.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Let me do some research on deriving from templates to override and make sure it works, as I am sure it will, and will mark it as answered.

Comment: @RobGoodwin Your welcome. You can download the sample I put together for your question from https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ni0dbcgzji5h8n/ListBoxSelectionWin8.rar to see the Style override.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks for taking the time to post the sample.  It allowed me to quickly test on Windows 7 and 8.  And it gives me some more sources current for learning about styling WPF controls.

Comment: @DefenestrationDay Not sure what you mean by that. "This method" mentioned in the answer is merely just a `Style` you're specifying with custom brushes than the ones from default. `AlternationCount` is a property which you can still set on the `ListBox` and say if you have a trigger such as `<Trigger Property="ListBox.AlternationIndex" Value="0"><Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Tomato" /></Trigger>` inside `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` of the `Style` you'll see the `Foreground` switch to `Tomato` just fine for items with index 0 as `AlternationIndex`.

Comment: Thanks!  Thought I was going mad for a moment!

Comment: Thanks so much I have tried several thing but only your ans worked for me.Thanks agian

Comment: Thank you very much! Been working on this for a long time, not realizing most solutions only work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 10):

Adding the following trigger to my Item DataTemplate, worked for Windows 10:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
    <Border Name="Border" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Padding="0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Medium" />
    </Border>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Most clean & concise solution that worked for Windows 8!

Comment: I wish I could upvote more. Way better than these other hacky solution above!

Comment: A nice workaround. However, the light blue selection rectangle is still visible in my case (Win 10 as of March 2023), but it's mostly overpainted by a slightly smaller rectangle with my own color. Both together look like a small light blue frame around my own colored rectangle. This 'frame' increases with the margin, and I use a quite large margin, so it looks really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

So you simply want to make the background of the selected item white?

Your code minus the ControlBrushKey setting works for me:

```
<Style.Resources>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="White" />
</Style.Resources>
```

Comment: Interesting, so after reading this I took my application to a Windows 7 box and it worked as expected.   But on my Windows 8 machine it does not.

Comment: Right, that works great pre-windows .Net 4.5 But for reasons unfathomable, the trigger values got changed from system brushes to hard-coded color values with dynamic resources. So, overriding those resources like that will no longer affect the ListBox. I assume the situation is similar for other controls, but I've only verified it so far on the ListBox.