# how to change the background of the selected item in a listbox?

Tags: wpf, background, listbox

I have this code:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />-->
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I would like to change the color of the selected item to greenLight for example, but it does not work, the selected background isthe same blue that when I don't use the item container style. However, the bold style of the text is shown.

How can I change the background of the selected item?

Thanks.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, not sure I unserstand but did you try `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen"/>`? Instead of setting it to `Transparent` set it to `LightGreen`.

Comment: Do remember that brush overrides for this would not work on Windows-8. You'd have to provide a custom `Style` yourself(base it on the default) and override directly. [As shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16820062/1834662)

Comment: Yes, I try to set lightGreen in the HighLightBrushKey. I am using windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue you can change template of ListBoxItem. Here is full code of style:

```
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        Padding="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```