# Style Bug? Can not set Background Color within Style in Windows10

Tags: wpf, combobox, windows-10

when i try to set the BackgroundColor for a ComboBox it's works fine in Windows7  but not in Windows 10. Is this the intended behavior or a bug?
EDIT: i dont mean the ComboBox Popup, just the Background Color of the plain ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>                 
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>            
  </ComboBox>
```

EDIT: just to get all the comments right, when i use this code:

```
 <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Background="Yellow"/>
```

All work fine and the combobox is yellow. But when i wanna do the same within a Style - i should expect that this should not work, because its intended? Seriously. This is what Styles a for!

[image: Windows 10]

[image: Windows 7]

Comment: It's not a bug, it is because the default template for the `ComboBox` control differs between the different versions of Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Change Background color of a Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695145/wpf-change-background-color-of-a-combobox)

Comment: Also possibly addressed here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819577/setting-background-color-or-wpf-4-0-listbox-windows-8

Comment: pls see my Edit. You all think thats its NOT the use of a Style to change the Background Color of a Combobox? i don't mean the Popup Background, just the plain Combobox.

Comment: How is this question still open?  The grey combobox colour is hard coded in the template for windows 10. The grey bit is not the background and it's not templatebound to the background. It's on top of the background.  Change the background and you will see no difference because the border is on top of it.  You need to change that template.

Comment: @Andy i just want to know why microsoft did this? it makes no sense to me.

Comment: I doubt there was a board meeting about the template changes. More likely a designer and developer. Or just an intern.   You'd have to find and ask the people who did the work. Since that would have been 9 or maybe 10 years back whoever did the work probably moved on from what remains of the wpf team quite some time ago.

Comment: Agreed, at first sight it may seem to make no sense and cause some "frustration" and make one to wonder: why, WHY? But if you think about it a little, it's actually pretty "genius". One may even say it is a case of "too much freedom"...:O) Here a couple scattered thoughts to consider: 1) `Background` is inherited from `Control`, so there's no written rule how it should be used in a `ComboBox` or anything else inheriting from `Control`.

Comment: 2) "Background" is just a name, a hint, some loose guidance, don't get too hung-up on it, it could as well be called "PropertyABC". The important thing is that it is a `Brush`. A `Brush` that you can use/bind (or not) as you please. If you wanted to, you could even use `Background` as your actual `Foreground` brush and vice-versa. Should you do it? Probably not, but it is nice to know you have the option... Not sure about y'all but we would take "too much freedom" 10 times over any other option. Besides, sure enough, there's always someone out there that will find some legit use case for that.

Comment: 3) Microsoft didn't take it lightly when it decided to make a control template fully configurable. And that includes your User Controls, your Custom Controls, and even Microsoft's own built-in controls! Again, "too much freedom"? You decide, just my 2 cents...:O)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you edit the default template:

[image: EditACopy]

You'll find the `ToggleButton` you're referring to is composed of a `Border` (set through the `ControlTemplate`) with a hardcoded `LinearGradientBrush`, that can only be altered by the `ControlTemplate`'s triggers.

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">

            <!--Left out for brevity-->

        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="F1M0,0L2.667,2.66665 5.3334,0 5.3334,-1.78168 2.6667,0.88501 0,-1.78168 0,0z" Fill="#FF606060" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                    <!--Left out for brevity-->

                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <!--Left out for brevity-->

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

To enable styling, you could forward the `BorderBrush` and `Background` properties to the `Border` through `TemplateBinding`.

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

        <!--
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        -->

        <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="F1M0,0L2.667,2.66665 5.3334,0 5.3334,-1.78168 2.6667,0.88501 0,-1.78168 0,0z" Fill="#FF606060" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        <!--Left out for brevity-->

    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```