# Listbox item does not change background after selection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem, wpf-style

I followed some answers online but it still fails. In the <Window.Resources> tag I add the following style

```
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#fff291"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False" >
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#013268"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

After I launch the program and select items, the foreground changes but the background remains unchanged. The color is the same as the one when the mouse hovers over the item.

[image]

As you can see, the first one is selected and the fourth one has a mouse hovering over it. The background color of the first one does not change as expected.
XAML for the Listbox is as follows:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="catDocListView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="16" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}">    
            <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #4</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
```

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: This is likely being controlled by the `ListBox`'s `ControlTemplate` and its Visual States.   You might want to take a look at it.  To do this, you can make a copy.  Add a `ListBox` to your view and look at it in the XAML Designer.  Then right click on the list box and select the options to make a copy of the template.  It will put the copy in one of your XAML files and then you can see how it works.  It's a great teaching tool by the way.

Comment: Set the properties for unselected items outside trigger. You don't need the trigger for IsSelected = false.

Comment: You better look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819577/setting-background-color-or-wpf-4-0-listbox-windows-8/16820062#16820062) answer ...